# Selecting pixel selections of the screen

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, 2d

How do I break down my screen into 10x10 pieces? The purpose is code optimization for a space invaders game. GridPane does not help me at all.

By breaking down the screen into equal 10x10 pieces, I will first check all 10x10 boxes and see if there is a bullet + a monster and then run the expensive part of the code (collision check).

So, how do I go about breaking down the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a two-dimensional array, which will let you access any 10x10 set of pixels on the screen.

For a 400x400 screen, do the following:

```
 Integer[][] boxes = new Integer[40][40];

      for (int i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < boxCount; j++) {
        boxes[i][j] = boxPosition;
        boxPosition += 10;
    }
    boxPosition = 0; //set pixel value at the start of the row to 0 for the next column.
}
```